# Is there a different way to inject the localstorage using the ng-toolkit/universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular8

I'm using a service(An auth service) to check whether the user is saved in the localstorage or not to save a new one or fetch if the user is already saved now I want to build with Angular universal so the localstorage causes an error so downloaded the package `@ng-toolkit/universal` and I inject the localstorage just like the documentation but it causes all the functions using the localstorage to throw and error

This is for a new Angular app using Angular 8, Angular Universal, `@ng-toolkit/universal`

```js
import { LOCAL_STORAGE } from "@ng-toolkit/universal";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthService {
  user: User;
  userLoggedIn = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClientService,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) public localStorage
  ) {}
  get isLogin() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      this.userLoggedIn.next();
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    }
  }

  register(body) {
    return this._http.post(body, "user/register");
  }
  login(body) {
    return this._http.post(body, "user/login");
  }
  saveUser(user) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    this.user = user;
  }
  updateProfile(body) {
    return this._http.post(body, "auth/applicant/profile/create-general-info");
  }

  get Token() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }

  // Get User Role
  get Role() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).role.role;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }

  get UserId() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).id;
    }
  }
  get User() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    }
  }
```

I expect the functions to work normally and correctly just like before the injection but they're not now the functions throw errors mostly isLogin and Token

Comment: Can you post the error here?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no. You cannot use `localStorage` in Angular Universal. The special injection is there only to be able to compile the code. But the `localStorage` only exists in the user's browser and is not available on the server. You can use `isPlatformBrowser` to check whether the `localStorage` is available. It this described in [this article](https://medium.com/@zainzafar/localstorage-with-angular-universal-2a111fb4af72)

Comment: I'm sorry but whenever I add the injection of localstorage I've errors on my local serve and the functions using localstorage throw errors